# How to make Confirm Popup when Reset Button is Clicked in Form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form at [www.thetotempole.ca](http://thetotempole.ca/formproject.html/) and I am wondering how a popup can be made when the reset button is clicked by the user asking if they really want to do this, if no I would like the text fields in the form to not be reset, if yes I would like the whole form and all of the text in the text fields to be reset. Thank you, as I can not seem to get this to work!

HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function validate()
         {
            var myform = document.getElementById("form1");
            myform.fname.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.lname.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.address.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.city.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.provstate.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.country.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.postalzip.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            console.log("form object: " + myform);
            if (myform.fname.value == "")
            {
               alert("First Name must have a value");
               myform.fname.focus();
               myform.fname.style.backgroundColor = "red";
               return false;
            }
            if (myform.lname.value == "")
            {
               alert("Last Name must have a value");
               myform.lname.focus();
               return false;
            }
            if (myform.address.value == "")
            {
               alert("Address must have a value");
               myform.address.focus();
               return false;
            }
            if (myform.postalzip.value == "")
            {
               alert("Postal/Zip Code must have a value");
               myform.postalzip.focus();
               return false;
            }
            else
            {
               //var regex = new RegExp();
               var regex = /^([a-z]\d[a-z]\s?\d[a-z]\d)|(\d{5}(\s?\d{4})?)$/i;
               myform.postalzip.value.toUpperCase();
               if (!regex.test(myform.postalzip.value))
               {
                  alert("Postal/Zip Code has invalid format");
                  myform.postalzip.focus();
                  return false;

               }
            }

            return true;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="form1">
         First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
         Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
         Address:<input type="text" name="address" /><br />
         City:<input type="text" name="city" /><br />
         Province/State:<input type="text" name="provstate" /><br />
         Country:<input type="text" name="country" /><br />
         Postal/Zip Code:<input style="text-transform: uppercase;" type="text" name="postalzip" /><br />
         <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to continue?')" value="Send" />
         <input type="reset" onclick="onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to reset?')" value="Reset" />

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks a bit garbled, with the onclick method having an onclick bit inside it:

```
onclick="onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to reset?')"
```

If you fix that, does it help?

Comment: yeah don't know how I didn't see that mistake before, WORKS